# Get number of pixels between two points in an Image

Tags: c#, winforms

I am working on a project which requires a number of pixels between two points which are horizontal in an image.  I am doing this in a windows application form.

Basically when a user clicks on one point in image and then on other point then he should get horizontal distance in form on number of pixels.

I am not getting any idea to do it.
please help.

Comment: You have literally no ideas?  If you had to do it on a photo in your hands, how would you approach it?  Think about that and then have a go writing some code which could do the same.

Comment: Which part of this are you having trouble with? Getting the points where the user clicked? Computing the horizontal distance between those two points? Displaying the result? One would think that you have *some* idea of how to do at least part of this.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your image is displayed using any control descended from `Control` then you will have access to the `Control.MouseClick` event ([link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mouseclick.aspx)).

This event uses `MouseEventArgs` ([link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.mouseeventargs.aspx)), which has a property X.

Should be pretty clear from that point.

**EDIT:** Added this very simple example:

```
private int? x1;

private void MyImageControl_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (x1.HasValue)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Difference of " + Math.Abs(e.X - x1.Value).ToString());
        x1 = null;
    }
    else
    {
        x1 = e.X;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this relative to the pixel density of the image though? I'd he's not showing a 1:1 relation the pixel diff will be incorrect.  That is of course of he needs the pixel distance in the image vs the display.

Answer (score 0):

For an image container, I am just using a pictureBox, though this would work with a label or whatever control you want.

Outside of any function:

```
private Boolean clicked_once = false;
private Point point1;
private Point point2;
```

And then I added a MouseClick event (not a Click event) :

```
private void pictureBox1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (clicked_once == false)
    {
        clicked_once = true;
        point1 = e.Location;
    }
    else if (clicked_once == true)
    {
        clicked_once = false;
        point2 = e.Location;
        int distance = Math.Abs(point1.X - point2.X);
        MessageBox.Show("Distance of pixels horizontally: " + distance.ToString());
    }
}
```

Should work.