# How to calculate distance between two points in an image and answer should be in number of pixels?

Tags: c#

I am not that good in c# programming. I'm just learning it. I have a small program where I have to calculate the distance between two points drawn by a straight line on an image and the result should be the number of pixels between them. I need to draw a line and as soon as I end the line I should get an answer in number of pixels. Can anyone help please?

Comment: How do you want to count the pixels? This is like using a vector from mathematics. Consider using theorem of Pythagoras

Comment: Yes you are right. But I am so confused hence, came here for help.

Comment: possibly duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10434833/get-number-of-pixels-between-two-points-in-an-image

Comment: Well that is what the program is all about. Its the LineLength and the answer should depict the number of pixels.

Comment: Yes but that is only for a horizontal distance. I need to find in all the directions possible. Just like if there is an image of someone and I click my mouse from one end of the nose to other and release it then it should tell me how many pixels are present in that region.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calculate pixels between two points on a image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9598867/calculate-pixels-between-two-points-on-a-image)

Comment: @Deanna but codes can be found through google. In fact thats how i have learnt c#.

Comment: @Deanna whatever link i have provided about exact duplicate, that question is also of c#. you can see it by tags

Comment: @Freelancer Sorry, I misread. Your suggested duplicate is not a duplicate as it's not working with diagonals.

Comment: @YanSklyarenko Your suggested duplicate is a different language and environment. While pythagoras is the theory, the exact answer will be different.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Pythagoras' theorem for this.

Assuming you want the distance in integer pixels, rounding up, then given two points the distance between them in pixels is:

```
public static int Distance(Point p1, Point p2)
{
    int dx = p1.X - p2.X;
    int dy = p1.Y - p2.Y;

    double distance = Math.Sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy);

    return (int) Math.Round(distance, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
}
```